# Errors were encountered while processing: rtl8821ce-dkms rtl8812au-dkms r8168-dkms

Tags: package-management, kernel, dkms

all. I am trying to install some new packages on my ubuntu 20.10 system but getting errors regarding dkms packages. There are many linux image.

```
$ rmadison linux-image-generic | grep groovy

 linux-image-generic | 5.8.0.7.7           | groovy           | riscv64
 linux-image-generic | 5.8.0.20.21         | groovy-security  | riscv64
 linux-image-generic | 5.8.0.20.21         | groovy-updates   | riscv64
 linux-image-generic | 5.8.0.21.22         | groovy-proposed  | riscv64
 linux-image-generic | 5.8.0.25.30         | groovy           | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x
 linux-image-generic | 5.8.0.48.53         | groovy-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x
 linux-image-generic | 5.8.0.48.53         | groovy-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x
 linux-image-generic | 5.8.0.49.54         | groovy-proposed  | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x
```

Hoping some easy solution.

Comment: We need to see the exact errors you're seeing, not what linux packages are on your system.

Comment: Let's start with this... Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: I was in hurry, so I installed 20.04 lts one more time. Sorry for inconvenience.